# Functions: Relations

Tags: functions, relations, function-and-relation-composition

I'm stuck on this question and would appreciate the solution, thanks!

> Let $R$ and $S$ be the relations on $A = \{1,2,3,4,5\}$ given by$$R = \{(1,2),(2,3),(3,4),(4,5)\}\\S=\{(2,3),(2,4),(3,4)\}$$Compute $R^2 = R \circ R$ and $S^2 = S\circ S$. Check that $S^2 \subset S$ while $R^2 \not\subseteq R$

Comment: $R^2= \{ (u,v) \mid \exists z \ [ (u,z) \in R \text { and } (z,v) \in R] \ \}$; thus e.g. $(1,3) \in R^2$.

Comment: Thanks but I'm a bit more confused, where did you get u, v and z from? I was kind of asking for a step-by-step solutions but thanks anyway, I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 6):

You could draw the relations on a piece of paper to make it clearer:

### R

$$
1\to 2\to 3\to 4\to 5
$$
and

### S

$$
\begin{array}{cc}
&&3\\
&\nearrow&\\
2&&\downarrow\\
&\searrow&\\
&&4
\end{array}
$$
and then squaring them means to form every relation that can be achieved by two consecutive arrows, so
$$
R^2=\{(1,3),(2,4),(3,5)\}
$$
and
$$
S^2=\{(2,4)\}
$$
Of course this can be found out without drawing anything. The graphical illustration only goes to strengthen your concept of what it actually means, I hope.

---

So in this diagram form the definition says that $x\to y\in R^2$ iff there exists $z$ such that $x\to z\to y\in R$ so for instance
$$
1\to3\in R^2\quad\text{since}\quad 1\to2\to3\in R
$$
In the usual format this is written as $(1,3)\in R^2$ since we have $(1,2),(2,3)\in R$ or generally speaking $(x,y)\in R^2$ iff there is some $z$ such that $(x,z),(z,y)\in R$.

Comment: +1 for drawings. I love drawings, they make things crystal clear.

Comment: +1 for drawings too! You must be the master of Latex! It's really clear.